# Default logins after installating SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, migration, logins

I migrated my old logins from a SQL Server 2017 instance to a newly installed SQL Server 2019 instance, by following Microsoft's guidelines:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances

Then I noticed 3 logins
##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##
##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin##
##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##
on both servers with a RED-X.
I don't remember whether these logins existed before the login migration, but I guessed that they were created by the login transfer process.

I decided to delete these 3 logins. Now, I am afraid whether these logins existed prior to my migration and that their absense might lead to some dysfunction that will require re-installing SQL Server 2019 in the future.

Can someone help me?

Is there a list with all the logins created after a simple installation??
Vasilis

Comment: Hi @AMtwo. Thanx for your quick reply . If this login is not needed on my new instance I'd rather not create it. I'm afraid that this login was created on installation. If it was created by the login migration script then I think i will be fine living without it.